# 'authapp' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

**Error Message**

> 'authapp' is not a registered namespace

I created Django an app in DJango and named it authapp. Root app name is practise 1 and inner app name is authapp. Below is the directory structure.

[image]

**Settings file code**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authapp'
]
```

Inside the inner app, the views.py code is below.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def login(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        return render(request, 'login1.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Below is the code in login template inside authapp.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'authapp:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Login
    </button>
</form>
```

Am I missing anything?

**Edit 1**

Below is code in urls.py in root

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('authapp.urls')),
    path('', views.home)
]
```

**url.py in authapp**

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

app_name = 'authapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login)
]
```

Comment: `__init__.py` ?

Comment: You haven't included the authapp urls in your root url conf

Comment: Added the `url.py` code, Please check my updated question. If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Add `app_name = 'authapp'` to authapp.urls

Comment: after adding the `app_name = authapp`,  got new error: `Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` Django Version is 2.2.6

Comment: @Pankaj can you show your authapp/urls

Comment: add the `url.py` in `authapp`, Please let me know if you need more info,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action="{% url 'authapp:login' %}"` here you are using the app_name `authapp` so you need to provide `app_name` inside your authapp urls also  like this:

authapp/urls.py

```
app_name='authapp'
urlpatterns = [..]
```

Also In django you don't need the parantheses in the *if condition*

EDIT:You need to name your url. see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names)

```
  path('login', views.login,name='login')
```

Comment: can u suggest something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740464/issue-while-trying-to-convert-into-class