# Issue while trying to convert into class

Tags: django

**This was my original code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def login(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        return render(request, 'login1.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**Converted above code to class below.**

```
class login(View):
    def loginForm(self, request):
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    def authenticate(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Inside Post")
```

**New Url.py file**

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

app_name = 'authapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login.loginForm(), name='loginForm'),
    path('', views.login.authenticate(), name='authenticate')
]
```

I got an error

> loginForm() is missing 2 required positional arguments: self and
>   request.

Can you please suggest something? I was actually trying to convert the code into class. Everything was fine without class.

Comment: You should really return a redirect from a successful POST, users are less likely to submit the same data again if they were to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to define a `get` and a `post` method on your view class. Each one will be called when the relevant request method is used.

```
class LoginView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'login.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Inside Post")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: I have already this thing in place but what will happen if there is method name called authenticate?